# avada wordpress theme woocommerce site google page speed score 0/100

Tags: wordpress

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SUsD.png

All required things did for site optimization but page speed score not increasing from 0.Please help. (See Above image)

Comment: Your question must contain the required information and code *in the question itself.* Have a look at how to make a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

I think you have too much images on your site, the loading time is 5 second and the weight is 21mb.
Try to install a plugin to load image on scrolling action..

If you try on pagespeed a url like https://orange-eyewear.co.uk/about-us/ it works.

Comment: So How can make faster this site.